# How i Do video face Swapping in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The face swap has become a time-honored tradition of Internet weirdness, and a new app lets you do it live, putting no wait time between the decision to do it and the feelings of regret that the results produce.

Comment: This question is out of the scope of SO

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly complex thing to make if you are starting out but to get started you will need to look into `AVCaptureSession` once you have the camera on the screen you will need to look into `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` this has different types of capture based meta data attachments you can use of which you will need:

```
AVMetadataObjectTypeFace
```

This will allow you to get delegate callbacks on

```
captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

Of which gives you the `Rect` of the faces found in the camera view. With that you can swap the rects on the `AVCapturePreviewLayer`.

Comment: ya ..i knw its so complex i search so much on net but i not find any thing but app is there

Comment: Above is exactly the route to take to make it

Comment: You will need more than just a rect for the face, you need landmarks for at least eyes, jaw and mouth. Have a look at opencv and cascade classifiers. Once you have landmarks you can use a procrustes algorithm to work out how to translate each face taking into effect any skew rotation or scale differences. Lastly come up with a good way to blend the faces maybe with laplacian blending. Good Luck!